# C++ keyboard input into 2 arrays

Tags: c++

I m trying to figure out following:
Let's say we ask a user for multiple lines input (each line has 2 values, one is a string and the other is a number; example: 
'milk 2.55'
'juice 3.15').
Now how can i run a loop to read all lines and assign to two different arrays (string input to string array and number to double array). Both arrays are set to value of 50 (array[50]) and i don't know how many lines user will enter. If i run a for loop and set ...i<50...it will fill both arrays up to 50 values (if we consider only 2 lines entered, each array will have 2 correct values added and 48 'garbage' ones).
I want to be able to read a line, assign each value to proper array and count how many values were added.

It works fine if i know how many lines there will be (like let's say 3)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string itemnames[50]; 
    double itemprices[50]; 
    double subtotal = 0, tax, total;
    const double TAX_RATE = 0.095;
    int count = 0;



    cout << "\nPlease enter the names and prices of the items you wish "
        << "to purchase:\n";



    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++){
        cin >> itemnames[i] >> itemprices[i];
    }



    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){

            subtotal += itemprices[i];

    }


    tax = subtotal * TAX_RATE;
    total = subtotal + tax;

    cout << endl;


    cout << left << setw(10) << "item"
        << right << setw(10) << "price" << endl
        << "--------------------" << endl;

    for (int j = 1; j <=3; j++){
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed
            << left << setw(10) << itemnames[j]
            << right << setw(10) << itemprices[j] << endl;
    }

        cout<< "--------------------" << endl

        << left << setw(10) << "subtotal"
        << right << setw(10) << subtotal << endl << endl

        << left << setw(10) << "tax"
        << right << setw(10) << tax << endl

        << left << setw(10) << "total"
        << right << setw(10) << total << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't know how many lines the user will enter, have you considered `std::vector` instead of `array[50]`?  Regardless, if you've tried *anything*, you should show it here, so we're not repeating work you've already completed.

Comment: @DrewDormann - code added

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to insert the elements into a single vector of a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) or [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) or a simple object like a `struct`.  this way you don't need to maintain two different collections of data and with the vector you can add as many items as you need.  Using a `struct` it would look like:

```
struct Item
{
    std::string name;
    double price;
};

std::istream & operator >>(std::istream & is, Item & item)
{
    is >> item.name >> item.price;
    return is;
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<Item> items;
    Item reader;
    // get items
    while (cin >> reader)
        items.push_back(reader);

    // display items
    for (const auto & e : items)
        std::cout << e.name << "\t" << e.price << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You can see an example of this running with this <kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/LenmWh)</kbd>

Comment: Well. I won't bother posting mine now. Fiend.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an array, its so old fashioned. Use a `vector` its simple.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<float> costs;
    vector<string> names;

    char choice = 'y';

    while(choice != y){
        float price;
        cout<<"Enter price: ";
        cin>>price;

        costs.push_back(price);

        string name;
        cout<<"Enter grocery name: ";
        cin>>name;

        names.push_back(name);

        cout<<"Enter y to continue";
        cin>>choice;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then you can simply do `names[49]` to get the 50th grocery name.

Comment: `names[50]` will give you the 51st item, which will be a problem if you only inserted 50 elements.

Comment: I have been using lua lately.

Comment: There's a language that doesn't use 0 based indices?

Comment: As far as I know in lua and MATLAB, arrays start from 1.